# Arkham City: Enable catwoman midway through story mode

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I have been playing a used copy of Arkham City and am thinking of purchasing the Catwoman DLC. Thing is I am already about 57% through the main story, (just defeated Mr Freeze). 
If I download catwoman now:

1. will i miss out on all the catwoman related content previously in
   the story?   If so how much have i missed out?
2. Will the rest of the catwoman related content be unlocked in the current 'story' or will i have to start a brand new game for that?

Comment: IIRC, the very first encounter in the game was a catwoman fight so I think you'd definitely miss those parts of the story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I downloaded the Catwoman DLC part way through my playthrough. To answer your questions, no, you will not miss out on the previous Catwoman content, although Slow is right and you will have to choose the previous missions from the main menu.

And your second question, yes, the Catwoman content will be unlocked in your current 'story', not needing you to start another game to enable it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if Catwoman's story is going to add itself to your current playthrough but there is a chapter on the main menu(before you launch your game) where you can replay only Catwoman's episodes. But if you wanna include Catwoman in Batman's story the right way I'd advise you to start a new game or wait for new game + before buying as you'll begin the game with her instead of the bat.